# How do I use server side encryption when uploading a file to s3 via the ruby sdk?

Tags: ruby, encryption, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm running into an issue uploading to S3 with version 2 of the sdk.

When running:

```
Aws.config.update({
      region: 'us-east-1',
      credentials: Aws::Credentials.new(credentials['key'],credentials['secret'],
      s3_server_side_encryption: :aes256)
})
s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new
bucket = 'VandalayIndustriesAccountingData'
s3_file_path = "folder/filename.tar.gz"
s3_object = s3.bucket(bucket).object(s3_file_path)
s3_object.upload_file(artifact_location)
```

I get the following error:

```
Aws::S3::Errors::InvalidToken
-----------------------------
The provided token is malformed or otherwise invalid.
```

When I remove the `s3_server_side_encryption` setting it changes to an access denied error.

I've been trying to find documentation around doing this with v2 of the API, but everything online seems to rely on the bucket object having a `write` method which doesn't seem to exist in v2 of the API.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/SSEUsingRubySDK.html

I'm likely just not finding the correct document in the v2 api.  I'd like to avoid using v1 and v2 of the api but may fall back to that.

Answer (score 0):

upload_file takes arguments similar to write

```
Aws.config.update({
  region: 'us-east-1',
  credentials: Aws::Credentials.new(credentials['key'],credentials['secret'],
  )
})
s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new
bucket = 'VandalayIndustriesAccountingData'
s3_file_path = "folder/filename.tar.gz"
s3_object = s3.bucket(bucket).object(s3_file_path)
s3_object.upload_file(artifact_location, server_side_encryption: :AES256)
```